# Loop though lines, Curl for a value, Store the Value

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to read a file, each line of which is a CVE ID.  For each CVE, I want to make a curl to get its severity and then store that result in a new CSV file with the format cve-id,cve-severity.

Below is the script I'm using, which reads the IDs correctly, but doesn't make the curl call correctly.  When I run this, it just outputs empty values for each curl call.

I've tried using back ticks instead of the $(), but same result.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash
 
filename="cves.csv"
 
while read line
do

    echo "$line"
    cve_result=$(curl -s "https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/${line}")
    echo "$cve_result"

done < $filename
```

Also tried these variations, all with same (empty) result:

```
cve_result=$(curl -s "https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/${line}")
cve_result=`curl -s "https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/${line}"`
cve_result=$(curl -s "https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/$line")
cve_result=`curl -s "https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/$line"`
cve_result=$(curl -s https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/$line)
cve_result=`curl -s https://cve.circl.lu/api/cve/$line`
```

Here is a sample of the CSV file:

```
CVE-2014-0114
CVE-2014-9970
CVE-2015-1832
CVE-2015-2080
CVE-2015-7521
```

Comment: that was the issue, good catch!  if you want to submit this as an answer, i'll accept.  thank you for the quick help @markp-fuso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me (ie, each `curl` call pulls down a bunch of data).

If I convert my (linux) file to contain windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`) then the `curl` calls don't generate anything.

At this point I'm guessing your input file has windows/dos line endings (you can verify by running `head -2 cves.csv | od -c` and you should see the sequence `\r \n` at the end of each line).

Assuming this is your issue then you need to remove the `\r` characters; a couple options:

- `dos2unix cves.csv` - only have to run once as this will update the file
- `curl ... ${line//$'\r'/}"` - use parameter substitution to strip out the `\r`

Comment: after using dos2unix on the source file, my script indeed works as expected.  passing files around from mac to windows to linux caused me some confusion today :/

Comment: keep in mind this can have an effect on data files as well as (shell) scripts (yeah, `\r` at the end of shell script lines can wreak havoc, too); someone will probably jump in with a link to a common set of SO Q&A's that cover this topic ...